# Is `sink(file="x.Rout", type="both", split= TRUE)` possible?

Tags: r, sink

My question is whether it is possible to log all R output, just as it would appear on my console, simultaneously also to an .Rout log file *and* to see it also on my console while running.

I understand that `split=TRUE` is not usually possible with `type=message`.  I know the zz open file "trick" to direct both R output and R message to the same log .Rout file (and I understand flush-race conditions; presumably, R could flush the same way to the file as it does to the terminal).

alas, I do not believe it is possible to log both of these outputs **and** see the output both on the screen and logged to a file.  I hope I am wrong.

Comment: Isn't it similar to what the package `reprex` does ?

Comment: FWIW, throughout my work on the future framework, I came, [after lots of considerations](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future/issues/67), to the conclusion that it is _not_ feasible to capture standard error. The main **showstopper** is the fact that the [capturing/sinking of stderr can _not_ be stacked](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/Wishlist-for-R/issues/55).  What you can do is capture condtions of class `message` and `warning`, which are often outputted to stderr, and the most common source of stderr output.

Comment: reprex seems way overkill.  I just want to sink easily, without Rstudio, installations, etc.  Henrik---can you please point me to how I should best capture messages and warnings and copy them (presumably) to the stdout stack, too, when any appear (and they can appear from libraries, etc, too).  do I replace the existing `message` and `warning` functions altogether?